# Fields as Lorentz group irreps, spin and motion equation

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, quantum-spin, representation-theory, chirality

My question touches quite a vast subject. I'm looking for a macroscopic answer without a lot of math, just the one needed to feel the answer.

We have $SO(3,1)$ lorentz group, we can give him all the good behaviour we want starting from orthochrony.

We want irreducible representation of it, so we start from the isomorphism of its algebra with the one of the double covering $SU(2) \times SU(2)$. This is much easier to deal with.

I will now use the notation:
$(x, y)$.
With $x$ the spin of $SU(2)_{Left}$.
With $y$ the spin of $SU(2)_{Right}$.
With $( , )$ the tensor product.

Scalar field: $(0,0)$.

It has 1 ndof and we can add another one making it complex.
The real field implies $\phi = \phi^{*}$.
The complex field implies $\phi \neq \phi^{*}$
The motion equation is Klein-Gordon and it uses at least power of 2 in fields.

Spinor field:

We have 2 inequivalent irreps:
$(1/2,0)$ and $(0,1/2)$
We can call the one on the left, left. The one on the right, right.
The first approach to this is to have complex Weyl spinors with spin 1/2, for a total of 4 ndofs.
When we lorentz transform the conjugate of a field, in a given chiral irrep, we end up with something belonging to the other chiral irrep.
ie:
\begin{equation}
\Psi_{R} = f i \sigma_{2} \Psi_{L}^{*}
\\
\Psi_{L} = f ( - i \sigma_{2}) \Psi_{R}^{*}
\end{equation}
Where f is a phase factor which we can conventionally choose as 1.

This means that if we direct sum the two chiral irreps, we don't end up with 2 additional ndofs, as they were already included in the complexity of the field.

We can create scalars under lorentz and parity transformations only combining those 2, so we create dirac spinors, with 2 ndofs from the spin and other 2 ndofs from the chirality/complexity of the field.

Question 1:

- Can we create real weyl spinors with an associated motion equation?
- Can we create real dirac spinors with an associated motion equation? I think these are Majorana spinors.

Vector field: $(1/2, 1/2)$

If we make the tensor product:
\begin{equation} 
1/2 \otimes  1/2 = 1 \oplus 0
\end{equation}

We end up with a 3 ndof field - which is what we use as a vector field - and a 1 ndof field.

Question 2:

- What happens to the scalar field of this tensor product?
- Can we make a complex vector field with an associated motion equation?

Comment: The question of whether we can impose chirality and/or reality conditions (Weyl/ Majorana/Majorana-Weyl spinors) depends on the dimension. See, e.g., Appendix A.7 of Sohnius' review (http://www-fp.usc.es/~edels/SUSY/Sohnius_Introducing%20SUSY.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the reference